# Key of song sung a cappella

Tags: voice, key, intonation

If someone starts singing a song a cappella, then is it necessary for this person to sing in one of the 12 Western keys (A, A#, B, C, C#, D, D#, E, F, F#, G, G#)? For example, would it be inappropriate for him to sing *between* 2 keys? What if a guitar is playing along and he is singing between 2 keys--should the guitar go down/up to match the singer's intonation, or should the singer change pitch to match the intonation of the guitar?

Comment: Chances are, the singer will go up/down to match the guitar, not the other way around. Guitars are pretty hard to re-tune on the fly.

Comment: @WithoutNameZin, please check my edits to confirm I haven't changed your original meaning.

Comment: Changed a little. Because what I have asked is: Is possible sing in some key that is not the 12 W.K ? If so, if a guitar start playing after the singer is singing between the keys, should the singer go down/up ?

Comment: But it's ok too. The answer will point to the same point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly, if a song is sung a cappella there's no guarantee the pitch won't be 'in the crack' between keys based on A=440 (or any other consistent scheme).   There's also no guarantee the same pitch will be maintained throughout the song.  That's one reason that 'just singing' a song into a recorder then sending it to a musician to have a track built round it is a bad idea.  (Another reason is that the timing is equally unlikely to be consistent.)